# Return middle of the text string

Tags: awk

The following awk statement is working as expected.
It returns 1st, 2nd and last 4 columns from a text file delimited by |

```
awk '{print $1,"|", $2,"|", $(NF-3), "|",$(NF-2), "|", $(NF-1),"|", $(NF)}'
```

I will like to return the middle columns in between. In other words I need to replace the $something from the following line to something that will work.

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $something, $(NF-3), $(NF-2) $(NF-1), $(NF)}'
```

There can be 3 to 11 columns those will replace the something variable.

Comment: Sorry didn't get. What's wrong with `awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $(NF-3), $(NF-2) $(NF-1), $(NF)}'` OR `awk '{print $1, $2, $4, $(NF-3), $(NF-2) $(NF-1), $(NF)}'` ?

Comment: I need to break up the file with | delimiter in 7 columns.

Comment: You can use: `'{ printf("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $(NF-3), $(NF-2) $(NF-1), $(NF); }'`

Comment: ## awk: line 1: missing ) near ;

Comment: Show some sample input and desired output, please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182998/merge-2-lines-into-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have understood what you are expecting your output to look like. Try this line of `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="|" } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i <= 3 || i >= NF - 3) printf "%s"OFS, $i; else printf "%s", $i; print "" }' file.txt
```

Test input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14
Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6 Y7 Y8 Y9 Y10 Y11 Y12 Y13 Y14
101 102 103 104 1010 1011 1012 1013 1014
```

Test output:

```
1|2|3|4567891011|12|13|14
X1|X2|X3|X4X5X6X7X8X9X10X11|X12|X13|X14
Y1|Y2|Y3|Y4Y5Y6Y7Y8Y9Y10Y11|Y12|Y13|Y14
101|102|103|10410101011|1012|1013|1014
```

HTH

Comment: Very close # test input is space separated and not | separated # test output may have space in forth column.

Comment: @shantanuo, Please consider posting some sample data. Where are you expecting the space in the forth column?

Comment: Instead of a long sequence of alternatives: `if (i <= 3 || i >= NF - 3)`

Comment: don't use a huge one-liner, use `awk -f file.awk` and post a nice formatted script with newlines...